# Import the table from an html website

Tags: import, web-access

I would like to import the data (table) from this website: http://dr.ittf.com/ittf_ranking/ittf_team_ranking.html

I don't know how to import and automatically change the date/year. Let's say, I want to import the table of several months in 2015, for example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first step is to identify URL to the data source. Inspecting the source code of the website, we find that the website consists of two iframes. The URL to leftmost iframe is

```
http://dr.ittf.com/ittf_ranking/team_ranking1.asp?FormName=Search&
FormAction=search&Gender=M&Month1=6&Year1=2017&Category=sen
```

This is the URL to the table. The next step is to identify the parameters from the URL so that we can easily build the URL corresponding to the table which we want to scrape:

```
url[gender_, month_, year_] := URLBuild[
  "http://dr.ittf.com/ittf_ranking/team_ranking1.asp", {
   "FormName" -> "Search",
   "FormAction" -> "search",
   "Gender" -> gender,
   "Month1" -> month,
   "Year1" -> year,
   "Category" -> "sen"
   }]

url["M", 6, 2017]

(* Out: "http://dr.ittf.com/ittf_ranking/team_ranking1.asp?FormName=Search&\
FormAction=search&Gender=M&Month1=6&Year1=2017&Category=sen" *)
```

Now we need to import the HTML into Mathematica and extract the information. This is traditionally done by importing the HTML as XML, and then using `Cases` to find the information. There are plenty of examples of that already in other questions. I will use my package, [jsoupLink](https://github.com/cekdahl/jSoupLink), to do the parsing. With jsoupLink it would look like this:

```
Needs["jsoupLink`"]
html = Import[url["M", 6, 2017], "HTMLDOM"];
rows = html["Select", "tr"][[7 ;;]];
columns = #["AllText"] & /@ #["Select", "td"][[{2, 4, 5}]] & /@ rows;
columns[[;; 10]] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I can't say more, but you are my HERO! How do you have a good knowledge about HTML parsing like that? wow! upvote for your kindness!

Comment: @ERT I used to do a bit of web development. I'm glad it helped.